# Google Cloud Platform: project appears in billing reports but doesn't show in the list of projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

Our organization uses Google Cloud APIs for integrating Maps and other services in a number of websites.

We have often used the same API key, without creating a distinct Google Cloud project (and credentials) for each website/project.

We are trying to better organize our API usage, but we are facing an issue.
While we can consult the reports of our Billing account and see the quota for the unique API project used for every implementation, **we cannot see and manage this project (it does not appear in the list) even though it seems to belong to the same organization**. *(EDIT: I am not sure that the organization id is the same, but the name of the organizazion appears as a prefix to the project name in the billing reports)*

This project has been created years ago (and the person that created it appears not to have access to it either), but we need to access it to get a clear understanding of where and how APIs are used.
The connected APIs are still in use and working, so we assume the project exists.

Can someone point out the possible reasons why a project is not shown even though it belongs to an organization for which we have access as administrators?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The main reason is: You can attach a billing account to any project (in your organisation or not) as long as you are Billing Account User. In my organisation, we have a group billing account and we delegate the project creation to subsidiaries (which are also brands) that have their own organization. Therefore they can use the group billing account but, at the group level, we can't access the project, only see their attachment to the billing account and their cloud consumption.

Comment: On solution is to remove the project from the billing account, and wait someone who ask you because something is going wrong!

Comment: You state `it does not appear in the list`. What list? If you go to the Billing Account, a list of projects attached to the billing account will appear. You can then click on the project to see its details. If you receive an IAM permission error when you click on the project, either add a Resource Manager role with `resourcemanager.projects.get` or ask the Org Admin to grant permission. You will need a Billing Account viewer role as well. Since you mentioned API keys also review the answer from @mensi.

Comment: @JohnHanley the project is included in the list of those attached to the billing account, but it is missing from those that can be managed by the organization (of which I am an Admin). I also can not get the project description.

I probably misinterpreted the way the project ID is presented, when in fact it doesn't belong to the organization (OP edited). I will investigate further.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did not remove the project from the billing account since it is still used by many of our websites, and configuring a new project for each of them will be a long process. We will have to check with the original project creator or create the new ones first.

Comment: In the Billing Account, look for the IAM members. One of those identities has enough rights to the project to attach it to a billing account. That person should be able to grant you permission to manage the project. Also, find out who the billing account owner is (that identity is listed in the billing account). That person can contact Google Cloud Billing support for additional help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see a project in lists, you need the `resourcemanager.projects.list` IAM permission on the project and to get it's metadata, the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission.

How did you find that it has the same organizationId? If you managed to get the metadata via `gcloud projects describe`, you are likely missing the `list` permission.

In any case, if the project is indeed part of the organization, an org admin should be able to use `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding` to add a new owner/editor.

There is a special case with Apps Scripts: [Those create a hidden project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects).

If all fails, reach out to GCP Support. Keep in mind though that they will not be able to help you if the project is not within your organization (eg. created with an unrelated gmail.com account or similar)

Comment: In the Reports section of the Billing account, I see the project ID listed as: **[ORGNAME]:api-project-[PROJNUM]**. Where _[ORGNAME]_ is the name of my organization, _"api-project"_ corresponds to the human-readable name of the project (_"API Project"_) and _[PROJNUM]_ corresponds to the one listed in the next column (_"Project number"_).

I assumed that having the organization name as a prefix implies that the project belongs to the organization. Is this is not the case?

This would explain why I could not obtain the project description or add a IAM policy.

Comment: api-project-* is one of those hidden projects, see the link in the answer.